# Flask socket IO - what is difference between send and return in socket.on method

Tags: reactjs, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm fetching data from flask with socketIO from react level :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
from flask_cors import CORS
import datetime
    
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) 
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*") # mayby too much CORS handling...

@socketio.on('time')
def time():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return current_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app)
```

in Flask it works ok, but if I switch to `send(current_time)` instead of `return current_time` I get undefined value in React, so what is difference between `return()` and `send()` in this case ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";

    
function SubscribeToTimer() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
      const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
      
      socket.emit('time', function (data) {
          console.log('time: ', data);
          setResponse(data);
        })
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
        <p>It's {response}</p>       
    </div>
  );
}

export default SubscribeToTimer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of a Socket.IO endpoint in Python is sent back to the client as an ACK packet (as in acknowledgement). The JavaScript client makes this value accessible to the application by passing the value in the completion callback of the `emit()` that originated everything:

```
socket.emit('time', function(data) {
    // data is what the Python event handler returns
});
```

When the server calls the `send()` function it emits a `message` event to the client, independently of the originating event that the client emitted to the server. To get the data from a `send()` call the client needs to implement an event handler for the `message` event:

```
socket.emit('time');
socket.on('message', function(data) {
    // data is what the Python side passes in the send() call
});
```